# Is my Cayenne plant healthy?

Tags: plant-health, peppers

I'm based in London, UK. I planted Cayenne around mid-may 2018, this is how they are currently looking like (leaves look a bit too big to me compared to other pics of the plants I've seen). So at around 60 days, I haven't seen any flowers blooming yet, so I'm thinking my plant will just be growing leaves and bearing no fruit, please look at the picture and assist if possible. Also how much water should I feed it please?:

[image: cayenne_plant]

Many Thanks!

Comment: How much sun does it get? Which such large leaves, I think it get too much shadow.